# libusb-1.0 libusb_get_device_list() failure

Tags: c, libusb, libusb-1.0

Also tested with -Wall and -std=c99 and c11 (not working of course)

```
$ gcc -o usb -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0 -I/usr/local/include usbtest.c
```

Output:

```
usbtest.c: In function ‘main’:
usbtest.c:14:1: error: label ‘brd_ftdi’ used but not defined
 libusb_get_device_list(context, &&brd_ftdi);
```

usbtest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
int main() {
  libusb_device* brd_ftdi;
  libusb_device_handle** brd_ftdi_handle;
  libusb_context* context;

  //libusb_device *** list = &&brd_ftdi;

  //libusb_init (libusb_context **);
  libusb_init (&context);

  libusb_get_device_list(context, &&brd_ftdi);
  //libusb_open(brd_ftdi, brd_ftdi_handle);

  //libusb_exit(struct libusb_context *); 
  libusb_exit(context);

  return 0;
}
```

Not defined? I know, but `libusb_get_device_list()` is supposed to do it (put the list in there), so WTF? I also tested declaring a pointer to pointer to `brd_ftdi` and passing that on instead but same result.

Answer (score 2):

If you read closely the error message, it says the *label* `brd_ftdi` is not defined, not the variable.

That is because you wrote `&&brd_ftdi`, the `&&` is a GCC extension that means [the address of a label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). It is not standard C.

The address of a variable is just one `&`. The address of the `brd_ftdi` variable is `&brd_ftdi`.

The [`libusb_get_device_list`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#gac0fe4b65914c5ed036e6cbec61cb0b97) function takes a `libusb_device***` : the address where it'll write the address of the list of pointers to `libusb_device`.
You can use it like this :

```
libusb_device **list_of_devices;
libusb_get_device_list(context, &list_of_devices);
```

`list_of_devices` is a pointer to the first pointer of the list (of pointers to `libusb_device`s).

You'll have a problem with your currently commented call to `libusb_open`, because you are passing an uninitialized pointer to a pointer to `libusb_device_handle`. This function too writes its result (the `libusb_device_handle *`) at the address you give.